# Formulae to calculate PWM output Timer (Counter settings) for STM32

Tags: stm32, stm32f4discovery

Need formulae to calculate Prescaler,Counter Period and a Pulse value of each channel on a Timer with  given values of

Input clock frequency (APB)
Output Frequency (PWM) 
Duty cycle (for each channel)

Answer (score 2):

Can you solve this equations?

`Frequency = ClockFreq / ((PSC + 1) * (ARR + 1))`

`Dutyin% = (CCRx * 100) / ARR`   for the fast PWM

Comment: @PeterJ01, How do I determine suitable ARR and PSC values ?

Comment: there is no one formula. If you know the `(PSC + 1) * (ARR + 1) ` you need to find the integer multiplication value which is as close as possible to the math one